# C#: Add the current instance to a list

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to create a list of all instances of a class. For that, I have made a static list of the class inside it and I want to add the instances inside of the constructor, however, I don't know what to reference!
Here is my code:

```
class File
{
    public static List<File> files = new List<File>();

    public string name;

    public File(string newName)
    {
        name = newName;
        files.Add(); //This is the line  I am having trouble with
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `files.Add (this)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use “[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this)” to reference the current instance.

```
files.Add(this);
```

Comment: Thank you! I searched for this but couldn't find it anywhere! you save my life!